# Which bootstrap 3 class should I use to create vertical list of items / "cards" (Rails 3.2, bootstrap3)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a daily deal app to learn Ruby on Rails.

I'm now building the home page view. I would like it to be simply a vertical list of "cards" (see https://www.intercom.com/blog/why-cards-are-the-future-of-the-web/), or more simply put, a vertical list of elements with each one being a horizontal rectangle with a grey border.

I'm new to Bootstrap and there are so many classes available.
Is there one I could use for these "cards", even if I have to override a little of its CSS afterwards?

Here is an example of the kind of "simple vertical rectangle list" I'd like to have.

[image: simple vertical rectangle list layout]

Maybe class "[list-group-item](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#list-group)" but my rectangles are all separated as you see in the picture (i.e they're not touching each other) and I need a red title above each rectangle (i.e the title is outside the rectangle/item) so I'm not sure it's the right choice.

Is there a better match for the class in Bootstrap 3 for what I want to do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What on top of my head is you spit out unordered list `ul` > `list-group-item` > `div` > more `div` > text

I made an example. checkout here https://jsfiddle.net/kuntau/X5Wvn/

HTML

```html
<div class="container" >
    <ul class="list-group">
    <li>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-info">
                    <p><strong>Tel: 011-345-898</strong></p>
                    <p>9182 Lorem Ipsum<br />
                        consectetur adipiscing elit.<br />
                       Nullam vel lacus felis.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-rating">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <p>Rate Yourself!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-more1">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
                    <br /><span>Caption</span>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-more1">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
                    <br /><span>Caption</span>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-more1">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
                    <br /><span>Caption</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.list-group li {
    list-style: none;
}
.panel-info, .panel-rating, .panel-more1 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you nest the panels into a list-group?

Answer (score 7):

How about using [panel with heading](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#panels-heading) and [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid) to fully utilize responsiveness:

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Item title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">first column</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">secondcolumn</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">3rd column</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">4th column</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">5th column</div>
        </div>
```

With just a little bit of CSS to render vertical borders:

```css
div.row > div:first-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
div.row > div:nth-child(5) {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bostaf/eqn93g6j/. Resize the viewport to see responsiveness in action.